# How can I set up a hotspot in my RV that rebroadcasts different WiFi signals?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, repeater

Thanks for looking and I apologize for the odd question--I am not really too sure how to ask it.

## Background

Here is my issue (#FirstWorldProblem): I have purchased a RV (camper) for my family and this summer we plan to take it on a month-long trip to several different parks. Having done this in the past, I am constantly playing "IT guy" for my family of 5 when we get to a new park and they all want their tablets, etc connected to the park's WiFi.

## Problem

I would like to create a single hotspot in the RV to which they always connect. When we get to a new park, I can setup the hotspot (once) and not need to connect the rest of the family's devices individually.

## Question

How do I set up this single hotspot that I can connect to a park's WiFi and then the other clients in our RV just connect to my hotspot. What equipment would I need?

## In case you are wondering

When we are camping, my wife and I frown on kids using their tablets, etc instead of enjoying nature. That said, there are rainy days, evenings, and just plain grumpy teenage girl issues that make it easier to just let them connect and stop making us miserable sometimes.

Thanks again!

Comment: This question is off topic here, but if you're running Windows 10 you can use this method - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/c60dcfa3-c596-41d4-8c1a-b0d738e1d9fd/use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot

Comment: For a permanent RV solution, I'd use an Access Point (AP) in client mode to connect to the parks wifi, then a standard router for your families devices, standard Ethernet cable between.  Certain services won't like the double NAT but most websites don't care anymore.